# Can C# properties be used whith GRPC-NET?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I have a lot of properties (get/set) in my project, and I want to use them as GRPC operations, should I consider them as methods or should I split them into 2 distinct methods ?

Does this following example work ? :

```
[OperationContract]
public string  FakeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        x = value;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried or read the documentation for OperationContract?

Comment: Won't work. [OperationContract] attribute can only decorate methods. These methods represent your service. You can use properties as DataMembers of a DataContract class (and use these as parameter or return value of a gRPC service).